# How to insert picture in the Delphi program itself?

Tags: delphi, timage

I have used a `TImage` component in my program.

At runtime, I add an image to the component by using:

```
Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\53941\Pictures\eq1.jpg');
```

Now, I want to run this program on some other computer, which would not have this image file at the source I have given in the code.

So, how can I store this image file in the program executable itself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Store the image file in the program's resources, using an `.rc` script or the IDE's `Resources and Images` dialog.  Read Embarcadero's documentation for more details:

[Resources and Images](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Resources_and_Images)

You can then use a `TResourceStream` to access the resource data at runtime.  Construct a `TJPEGImage` object, load the stream into it, and assign it to the `TImage`:

```
uses
  ..., Classes, Jpeg;

var
  Strm: TResourceStream;
  Jpg: TJPEGImage;
begin 
  Strm := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, '<Resource identifier>', RT_RCDATA);
  try
    Jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
    try
      Jpg.LoadFromStream(Strm);
      Image1.Picture.Assign(Jpg);
    finally
      Jpg.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Strm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can assign the image using the Object Inspector when designing the Form. The image will be stored in the Form's DFM and be loaded automatically when the program runs.

Select the `TImage` and, in the Object Inspector,

- select the `Picture` property
- click the <kbd>...</kbd> button to open the Picture Editor
- press the <kbd>Load...</kbd> button and select the image file
- Close the editor with the  <kbd>OK</kbd>  button.

If you want to load the image in code instead, simply do as Remy showed.

Comment: Using a resource is better because you can keep the asset directly in your revision control system. Pushing it into the .dfm file makes traceability harder.

Comment: Sure, but that is the usual, RAD way.

Comment: Yes. And it sucks. Speaking as a software developer.

Comment: It depends on your needs. For simple programs, or mockups, or simply for starters, it makes a lot of sense. If the program then gets larger, you can always refactor.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the dfm will store a bitmap. Might be unadvisable for large images.